# mp4 file ,mobile safari ,tomcat 7.0 playing ,iis 8.0 not playing

Tags: tomcat, iis, video, mobile-safari, mp4

I have a video file name test12.mp4. The file is hosted on `IIS` as well as `Tomcat`. When I try to play this file using Tomcat on mobile Safari it is playing fine but the same file which is hosted on `IIS` is not playing on mobile Safari.

I have already tried below setting:

1. Setting `mime-type on IIS` ...Still didn't work
2. View http header for response/request on mobile safari using `"mobile safari : web inspector"`. Both http headers are the same